# Force to ko.observable manually to notify subscribscription on page load

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm trying to trigger `self.selectedNavigation` subscription each time my page loads. I have tried the code below, but it is not working.

```
self.selectedNavigation = ko.observable(-1);
self.selectedNavigation.extend({ notify: 'always' });
self.selectedNavigation(self.navigations()[0].id());
self.selectedNavigation.valueHasMutated();

self.selectedNavigation.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    alert(newValue);
});
```

Is this even possible? if yes, how do I trigger it?

Comment: You have to `subscribe()` before actually modifying the value. Move the last line right after the creation of the `observable`. See https://jsfiddle.net/p88pgjt5/

Comment: if I do that, it will result in 'Unable to get property 'subscribe' of undefined or null reference'

Comment: You need to move it to the second line in your snippet (*after* creating the observable), not to the first one.

Comment: Yes, thanks that worked. can you move your comment to answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a subscription to get notified for changes, it has to be registered before the actual change has occurred:

```
// first defining the observable
self.selectedNavigation = ko.observable(-1);

// subscribing for changes
self.selectedNavigation.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert(newValue);
});

// mutating value
self.selectedNavigation(1);
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p88pgjt5/1/)